# Android studio unresolved reference for lazy (kotlin)

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I'm using Android Studio 3.5.3, kotlin plugin 1.3.61. But Android Studio doesn't see lazy function and highlight it red color. 
`private val fabX: Float by lazy { screenWidth - fabSize - fabMargin }`

I still can build my app, but syntax highlighting is broken. Is there any way how to fix it?

Comment: Syntax highligting in general is broken? Try clicking on the left and go to Restart & Invalidate Cache on Android Studio

Comment: What type `screenWidth`, `fabSize` and `fabMargin` of? Are those of Float?

Comment: please post the full snippet of code where you are using it

Comment: You can try **private val fabX: Float by lazy { (screenWidth - fabSize - fabMargin).toFloat() }**

Answer (score 3):

Checkout this solution:

- Go to `C:\Users\YOUR_USER` (Windows) or `~/` (Linux)
- Delete **`.AndroidStudio[version]`** folder
- Restart android studio

Following options did **not** work:
* Invalidate cache and restart
* Clean project
* Reloading project from repo

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved my problem by updating my dependencies versions in build.gradle here:

[image]